# 500 Internal Server Error while trying to write to a file in Python

Tags: python, permissions, cgi

I have a python script save.cgi in public_html/menuProject/ on a server example.com

I'm able to access the script from the browser by calling `example.com/menuProject/save.cgi?xml=Hello` and display "hello", but when I try to write to a file, it gives me 500 internal server error.

```
import os, sys
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
xml = form.getvalue("xml")
resultFile = "feed.xml"
print "hello"
with open(resultFile, "w") as f:
    f.write(xml)
```

Both `save.cgi` and `feed.xml` are in the same folder `public_html/menuProject/`
 and the file permissions for `menuProject` and all files is :`-rwxrwxrwx` 
.

Can you please help me figure out why it still is giving me 500 internal server error?

Comment: Have you checked the error log for your web server?

Comment: Have you checked that your server is running python 2.6 or 2.7 - if it is 2.5 you need to specifically enable with and older ones don't support it at all.

Comment: @SteveBarnes it is python 2.6.4
I'm still unable to figure it out. Why doesn't calling a script from the browser work? Is there a work around to trigger a script to write to a file from the browser other than this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Jon Clements

I did a :
`print sys.version` and found out that the webserver version was 2.4 while the code was in 2.6

Got it working by removing the `with`.

```
import os, sys
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
xml = form.getvalue("xml")
resultFile = "feed.xml"
print "hello"
f = open(resultFile, "w")
f.write(xml)
```